# Can't use Zip command

Tags: zip, system

```
zip -rmT smsgate.log.2019-03-20.zip smsgate.log.2019-03-20
```

I used the above command. But i got the below error message.

```
zip warning: name not matched: smsgate.log.2019-03-20

zip error: Nothing to do! (try: zip -rmT smsgate.log.2019-03-20.zip . -i smsgate.log.2019-03-20)
```

Comment: I just got stuck with this for an hour `zip -9 zipfile.zip .` should have had a wildcard, like `zip -9 zipfile.zip *` or `.*` | the zip documentation wasn't clear on this, because it says folder/path with NO mention of wildcard

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the file `smsgate.log.2019-03-20` doesn't exist, or is not at the place you expect.

Or perhaps the file is named `smsgate.log` instead?

What happens if you try first `zip smsgate.log.2019-03-20.zip smsgate.log.2019-03-20` ?